# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, data-visualization

i want to find degree holders.
The following code is causing AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'find' and I do not how to fix it:

```
edu = Edu_data

# Function to identify degree
def degree(x):
    #if x.find('Bachelor') != -1 or x.find("Bachelor's") != -1 or x.find('BS') != -1 or x.find('bs') != -1 or x.find('Bs') != -1 or x.find('Bachelors') != -1 or x.find('Undergraduate') != -1 or x.find('graduated')!= -1 or x.find('BSE')!= -1 or x.find('Enginee') != -1 or x.find('BCS') != -1:
    if x.find('Bachelor') != -1 or x.find("Bachelor's") != -1 or x.find('BS') != -1 or x.find('bs') != -1:
        return(1)
    if x.find('Master') != -1 or x.find("Master's") != -1 or x.find('M.S') != -1 or x.find('MS') != -1 or x.find('MPhil') != -1 or x.find('MBA') != -1 or x.find('MicroMasters') != -1 or x.find('MSc') != -1 or x.find('MSCS') !=-1 or x.find('MSDS')!=-1:
        return(2)
    if x.find('PhD') != -1 or x.find('P.hd') != -1 or x.find('Ph.D') != -1 or x.find('ph.d') != -1:
        return(3)
    else:
        return(0)

    
# Create degree column
edu['deg'] = list(map(degree, edu['Last_degree']))

edu
```

The full traceback for the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-9a79283a9b17> in <module>
     16 
     17 # Create degree column
---> 18 edu['deg'] = list(map(degree, edu['Last_degree']))
     19 
     20 edu

<ipython-input-39-9a79283a9b17> in degree(x)
      5 # Function to identify degree
      6 def degree(x):
----> 7     if x.find('Bachelor') != -1 or x.find("Bachelor's") != -1 or x.find('BS') != -1 or x.find('bs') != -1 or x.find('Bs') != -1 or x.find('Bachelors') != -1 or x.find('Undergraduate') != -1 or x.find('graduated')!= -1 or x.find('BSE')!= -1 or x.find('Enginee') != -1 or x.find('BCS') != -1:
      8         return(1)
      9     if x.find('Master') != -1 or x.find("Master's") != -1 or x.find('M.S') != -1 or x.find('MS') != -1 or x.find('MPhil') != -1 or x.find('MBA') != -1 or x.find('MicroMasters') != -1 or x.find('MSc') != -1 or x.find('MSCS') !=-1 or x.find('MSDS')!=-1:

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'find'
```

[image of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNPL7.png)

Comment: your `x` is a float, and it doesn't have `find`. You are probably passing a wrong argument.

Comment: a mystery :)
Apparently, a float number entered that function. Are you sure there are no floats in the column Last_degree?. It seems you need to debug it more. Maybe check for the type and print the value if it is a float so you can at least see what was passed

Comment: there are no floats in last_degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the image show all your data. Is it possible that somewhere in the data frame's `Last_degree` column contains a `float`?

If yes, change this line:

```
edu['deg'] = list(map(degree, edu['Last_degree']))
```

to

```
edu['deg'] = list(map(degree, edu['Last_degree'].astype(str)))
```

Comment: So there definitely is at least one float in `Last_degree`.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to Nan values remove them by replacing with something

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).